# Finding the average of a column in a matrix with unknown elements

Tags: java, eclipse, matrix

Can anyone help me with my code? I have to find the average of every column in a matrix but I don't know what's wrong with my code cause it doesn't work.This is my code:  (By the way it shows no mistakes and I had to put the numbers with JOptionPane, thanks for your help)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Matrix {
    private static final int String = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] numbers = new double[10]; // 10 doubles
        double sum = 0.0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {    
            sum += numbers[i];
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");
            double d = Double.parseDouble(input);
            double avg = 0.0;
            avg = sum/numbers[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "don't know what's wrong with my code cause it doesn't work" - have you tried debugging into it to find the problem? This statement seems to imply you found the code somewhere and just copied it without trying to understand it...

Answer (score 2):

You never assign any numbers to your `numbers` array, so they all default to 0.

Try:

```
numbers[i] = Double.parseDouble(input);
double avg = 0.0;
sum += numbers[i];
avg = sum / (i + 1); // (i + 1) is the number of inputted numbers
```

Comment: I can't add numbers in the array..I have to add them with JOptionPane

Comment: then make sure the JOptionPane is populating the array

Comment: Which you aren't assigning them to the array.  You assign double 'd' the input from the JOptionPane, but then do nothing with that 'd'.

Comment: I added sample code to assign the input to the numbers array and calculate the new average.

Comment: j/k  assign them to the array. Look up some tutorials on using java arrays.